# Plotting 2 lines in R with different x axis

Tags: r

I have 2 data frames x and y that I have to merge.

Then I want to plot 2 lines:

line 1= The "vol" that came from the x data frame
line 2 =  the "vol" that came from the y data frame

Both lines will should have "strike" on the x axis.

I am running in to errors. I think it is because the x-axis is not the same.

Can you help?

I would really like to use ggplot.

Here is my code that you can run:

```
x<- data.frame(strike= c(1,2,2.5,7), term= c("H15"), Vol = c(6,7,8,9), file="a")
x
y<- data.frame(strike= c(1,2,2.75,7), term=c("H15"), Vol = c(7,9,10,12),file="b")
y
main<- merge(x,y, by = "strike", all= TRUE)
main

strikes<- factor(main$strike,levels=c(main$strike),ordered=TRUE)
strikes

stacked <- data.frame(time=strikes, value =c(c(x$Vol), c(y$Vol)) , variable =   rep(c("a","b"), each=NROW(x[,1])))  
stacked

MyPlot<- ggplot(stacked, aes( x = time,  y=value, colour=variable, group= variable)  )   +   geom_line()  
MyPlot
```

Comment: The example code provided has some issues - the `stacked` object has vectors of varying sizes and hence cannot be bound into a data frame. Please verify.

Comment: Thats the question....

Comment: Oops... I thought it was just a plot issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with `reshape2` and `gpplot2`:

Firs let's melt your data:

```
library(reshape2)
x.melt<-melt(x[,c("strike", "Vol")], id="strike")
y.melt<-melt(y[,c("strike", "Vol")], id="strike")
x.melt[, "variable"] <-"Vol.x"
y.melt[, "variable"] <-"Vol.y"
data <- rbind(x.melt, y.melt)
```

With this we have:

```
  strike variable value
1   1.00    Vol.x     6
2   2.00    Vol.x     7
3   2.50    Vol.x     8
4   7.00    Vol.x     9
5   1.00    Vol.y     7
6   2.00    Vol.y     9
7   2.75    Vol.y    10
8   7.00    Vol.y    12
```

No we can use this with `gpplot2`:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data, aes(x=strike,  y=value, colour=variable))   +  geom_point()+ geom_line()
```

The result:

[image]